# Gmail text not appearing in Firefox

Tags: 12.04, firefox, google

On Ubuntu, I was working with a single user till yesterday. The GMail chat app was working on Firefox.

This morning, I installed Google Chrome, created a parallel user as an administrator, and logged into the parallel user.

Lo and behold, everytime I log in to google related sites, there is no font or character being displayed. I checked this on chrome, and texts are intact!

To be sure, I deleted the `./mozilla` folder in the home directory, but the problem persists.

What is the reason that this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood the way you installed Chrome messed up some font used by Firefox. Google Chrome is not officially supported on Ubuntu, not available from the official repositories and no automatic updates are released for it. You should have installed Chromium instead; you'll find it in the Software Centre.

Comment: It appears that it was a problem with some M$ fonts! I removed the set and voila!